# Ajax request contains odd data in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am performing this request:

```
 $.get("getdataforcharts", {q: ["test"]}, function (response) {
       alert( "success" );
    }).done(function() {
       alert( "second success" );
    });
```

The URL I expect should be: /testpage/getdataforcharts?q=test

However I get this: /testpage/getdataforcharts?q%5B%5D=test

How do I remove the "%5B%5D"?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Pass `q` a string instead of an array of strings *or*
2. Set `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` (where "traditional" means "not PHP-style")

Answer (score 0):

%5B%5D is [] when decoded, its your square brackets
try:

```
$.get("getdataforcharts", {q: "test"}, function (response) {
    alert( "success" );
}).done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
});
```